# Apply a function to a list of items

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have defined a function `f` that returns the `price` of an item `x` that is stored inside a list of prices with type `[(String,String,Int)]`

```
a = String
x = String
price = Int
pricesList = [(a,x,price)]

f a x ((a1, x1, price):ys) | a == a1 && x == x1 = price
                           | otherwise = f a x ys
```

I have to apply this function to a list of items, but I'm stuck. Is this possible using map? I couldn't figure it out.

(The only function that can use recursion is f)

**Edit. some examples to clarify a bit**

```
pricesList = [("apple","ipod",100),("apple","iphone",200),("samsung","galaxy",200)]
moneySpent = [("harry",1985,"apple",["iphone","ipod"]),("george",1983,"samsung",["galaxy"])]

*Main> f "apple" "iphone" pricesList
200
```

I need to know how much money a person spent by defining a new function, let's say `spentBy` (and using `f` inside of it)

```
*Main> spentBy "harry"
300
```

What I have done so far:

```
itsThePerson name (n,_,_,_) = name == n

infoFrom name = (head . filter (itsThePerson name)) moneySpent

brand (_,_,b,_) = b
product (_,_,_,p) = p

brandPerson = brand . infoFrom
productPerson = product . infoFrom
```

Is it possible to use `map` with function `f` to know the sum of the prices of the products that a person bought?

(function `f` would be function `itemPrice`)

```
spentBy name = sum (map (itemPrice (brandPerson name) xxx pricesList) (productPerson name)
```

Am I thinking it in the right direction?

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are trying to do. If you have an assignment, try quoting it verbatim. If you are trying to perform some real-world task, describe the task.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, `f` is a function that looks up the price for an item, and `list` is a list of items for which you want to find the prices. Is that correct?

Comment: @mhwombat Yes, that is correct. I need to apply function `f` to a list of items instead of just one item. Is that possible using map?

Comment: In future, instead of rewording your question, it would be better to add any clarifications to the bottom.

Comment: `map` takes a list and a transformation function, and returns an elementwise transformed list. What kind of list do you have? What kind of list do you want to get?

Comment: @n.m. First, I would like to clarify that I can't modify function `f`. Now, what I have as input is a list of `x's`, that is, a list of strings. And I need to apply function `f` to that list of strings to find the `price` of each `x`. So, the return must be a list of prices, that is, a list of `Int` (After that, I need to sum the prices, but that is not a problem). My main issue is how to apply function `f` to a list of `x's` instead of just one `x`. Is it possible to use `f` with `map`? Or maybe another function could be better?

Comment: Your function `f` seems to take *two* strings, but you have a list of strings. That is, each element is a solitary string. But you need to pass two strings to `f`, which you call `a` and `x` (and also the inventory list, but that's not the problem). If you have a list of `x`s, where do you get `a` to pass to `f`?

Comment: @n.m. I added  more information and examples.. I think it's more understandable now. I tried to resume it when created the question, but didn't work well. Thanks.

Comment: It is more understandable now but is also more complicated. So you have a list `moneySpent` and a list `pricesList`, and you want to query the two lists. Suppose George has purchased three iPhones, two iPads, and one Galaxy. You probably need to (1) build something like `[("apple","iphone"), ("apple","iphone"), ("apple","iphone"), ("apple","ipad"), ("apple","ipad"), ("samsung","galaxy")]` out of `moneySpent` list, and (2) run `map` on this new list. Can you do (1) and (2) separately?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you've got a three-argument function:

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

and a list of `c` values - `list :: [b]`. Let's say we want to apply `f` to each item in the list, with fixed first and second arguments. So we can do something like that:

```
map (f x y) list
```

where `x::a` and `y::b`.

The only difference from your case is the order of arguments. For this kind of issues, use `flip`:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)

--original function
f :: a -> b -> c -> d

--partial application
f x :: b -> c -> d

-- flip
flip (f x) :: c -> b -> d

--partial application again
(flip (f x) y) :: b -> d

map (flip (f x) y) list :: [d]
```

In your case it'll probably result in something like `map (flip (f a) prices) list`.

Answer (score 2):

If you provided a type signature for `f`, it would be clearer what you were trying to do. I'm going to assume that the third argument of `f` is a list of `(item #, description, price)`. An example would be:

```
priceList = [(1,"item 1", 1), (2,"item 2", 22), (3, "item 3", 333), (4, "item 4", 4444)]
```

Then the list we plan to map over must look something like this:

```
list = [(1,"item 1"), (3,"item 3"), (4, "item 4")]
```

We can map over `list` like so:

```
map (\(itemId, desc) -> f itemId desc priceList) list
```

You could instead write `f` to take two parameters, combining the first two into a tuple `f (a,x) ((a1, x1, price):ys)`. The all you need is `map f list`.

Finally, you haven't handled the case where the price isn't in the list. You could do something like this:

```
 f _ _ _ = error "item not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified answer: 
The overall problem you're trying to solve,

- Given a function f that takes 'itemId', 'itemName' and 'priceList'
  and returns a price.
- You want a function that uses f to return a list of prices from a list of [(itemId, itemName)]

In terms of type signatures, given:

```
f :: String -> String -> [(String, String, Int)] -> Int
```

and you want:

```
myLookup :: (String -> String -> [(String, String, Int)] -> Int) -> 
                [(String, String, Int)] -> [(String, String)] -> [Int]
```

where the first argument is the lookup function `f`, a priceList and an itemList, and the output is a list of prices.

```
myLookup f priceList itemList = map (\(itemId, itemName) -> 
                                          f itemId itemName priceList)
                                    itemList
```

The second argument to `map` is a lambda that extracts the two attributes from the itemList and looks up the values using `f`.

Comment: itemID and itemName correspond to first and second elements of the list of tuples `[(String, String, Int)]`. The problem is that the function `f` cannot be modified. The idea was to use `map` to return a list of values and after that generate the `sum` of them.

Comment: @warty: Corrected the answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem:

```
f a x ((a1, x1, price):ys) | a == a1 && x == x1 = price
                           | otherwise = f a x ys
```

Used a new function `f2`

```
f2 a x = f a x pricesList
```

Then

```
pricesList = [("apple","ipod",100),("apple","iphone",200),("samsung","galaxy",200)]
moneySpent = [("harry",1985,"apple",["iphone","ipod"]),("george",1983,"samsung",["galaxy"])]


spentBy name = sum (map (f2 (brandPerson name)) (productPerson name))

itsThePerson name (n,_,_,_) = name == n

infoFrom name = (head . filter (itsThePerson name)) moneySpent

brand (_,_,b,_) = b
product (_,_,_,p) = p

brandPerson = brand . infoFrom
productPerson = product . infoFrom
```